# Docker Add Directory to Container to Run Flask App

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
 +--mlservice
 |   __init__.py
 |   production
 |   requirements.txt
 |   venv
 |   DockerFile
```

where *production* is a directory and *init.py* is the main script.

This is my DockerFile.

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV FLASK_APP "mlservice/__init__.py"

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install the dependencies specified in requirements file
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy all directories and files from host to container
COPY . /app
COPY production /app/mlservice/production

EXPOSE 5000

# Run the application; default command to run when container starts
CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

My app runs fine in my Virtual Environment when running in Command Prompt, but when I try to run it in the Docker Container I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/app/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from production.dataprocessing import DataProcessing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'production'
```

I have tried all different ways to COPY my directory into the container, but to no avail. I do not think that I have a problem with relative imports because the *production* folder is found successfully when running in Command Prompt. I think the problem lies in how I am copying the *mlservice* directory to the container. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably move your `requirement.txt` into the `production/` directory then do something like:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV FLASK_APP "/app/__init__.py"

COPY ./production /app/production
COPY ./__init__.py /app/__init__.py

WORKDIR /app

# Install the dependencies specified in requirements file
RUN pip install -r production/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

# Run the application; default command to run when container starts
CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

This has the added advantage of:

- Not copying the `venv` folder into the image
- Not copying the Dockerfile into the image.

You could probably do away with the fourth line that copies `__init__.py` into the container by itself, by putting this in the production directory also, but this would depend on what the code looks like.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I have tried all sorts of variations of this, but none are allowing me to run the service.

Comment: I think `production/` must contain a blank `__init__.py` to import it as a module like this. is there a github repo of all this for wider context?

Comment: I added a blank __init__.py to the production folder, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: You need the double underscores on each side of `__init__.py` though I gues you know this... You're probably so close! You don't happen to have a github repo of this available?

Comment: I have the double underscores on the init.py...Stack Overflow bolds that. I don't currently have this publicly available, I will anonymize it and post it if I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: @JCM During the build stage, before it fails you'll see a line like `Step 7/8` followed by `---> f172e53dc0b7`.  That's the partial image id.  You can shell in to this with `docker exec -it f172e53dc0b7 /bin/sh` which lets you explore.  Try to figure out in there what doesn't look right.  Notice you begin in `/app` which is the result of the `WORKDIR` line.  From there you should be able to run the flask command to launch.  Good luck.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I am not certain which of my changes fixed the problem. One problem was actually unrelated to Docker itself. I had a log file that could not be found. I kept the structure the very similar but added a layer:

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, but I am not certain which of my changes fixed the problem.

I kept the structure very similar but added a layer under "mlservice" called "app" and added an init.py to the "production" directory:

```
 +--mlservice
  |--app
    |--main.py
    |--production
       |--__init__.py
       |--dataprocessing.py
    |--requirements.txt
    |--venv
    |--DockerFile
```

I was able to simplify the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "app/main.py" ]
```